# Android fragments disappearing after updating app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app which is working fine on version x on playstore. I have recently built a beta release for version x+1, after updating to the beta release some of the fragments on the home screen are not rendering. Strange thing is, if I freshly install the app to version x+1 (instead of updating from version x), the fragments are being rendered. Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to solve it?

Comment: Did the lifecycle methods of the fragment called properly? Can you put log and check.

Comment: Ya they were, found out the issue was because of my SharedPreferences, they had a different value than expected while updating